# What 4x4 lumber is appropriate for a skybed lounger swing?

Tags: wooden-furniture, porch-swing

I am going to build a sky bed lounger. ( a 4-pod swing made from a trampoline) I have the 4 point steel bracket that needs 4x4 wood in each slot. It looks like this:

[image]

I would like this to hold a 6-foot trampoline base (just base no legs etc) which is roughly 4 stone in weight. What is the best wood that will be strong enough to hold this structure and what screws would I need for the bottom? I'd secure rope from each bottom base to secure the legs of the swing and stop the wood bending.

Comment: I think you need to show a photo and/or provide a comprehensible sketch of what you are trying to do. If you made a tripod out of suitably long 4x4s those should be able to have their lower ends just lodged into the ground without further ado. A tripod (three legs by the way) of regular pressure treated 4x4s should be able to hold up a whole lot of weight. Probably more than the chains, hooks or links that you would use to hold up the trampoline.

Comment: Thanks Michael Karas  how do i upload a photo?

Comment: There is a photo of the bracket....scroll down the page, its called Top Bracket for 4-Pod Stand http://www.electronicbookshere.com/Floating_Bed/Floating_Bed.html

Comment: There is an ICON above the edit box that allows you to insert a picture from either your computer of from a web URL. Policy at StackExchange indicates preference for including pictures directly instead of links because external links can expire or go dead.

Comment: I added the picture for you. You still need to clarify what addition you are planning. That bracket is made for hanging everything  down from the single point loop. The legs should go from the bracket to the ground without anything additional being attached to them. Pressure treated 4x4's are plenty strong.

Answer (score 1):

Virtually any 4x4 lumber will be more than strong enough. Pressure-treated SPF would be fine, as would untreated pine/fir or cedar. You won't break a good-quality 4x4, as each is only carrying roughly a quarter of the load.

Screws are almost unnecessary here, but almost anything that fits the holes well is fine. They carry very little load and simply prevent the thing from falling apart when being transported. 1/4" lag screws or heavy construction screws come to mind.

Comment: Thanks guys...Michael thankyou so much for the edit...i have a link that shows what i am trying to make...its a 2 min video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJxBlI-x7GU it shows exactly what i am trying to make. Thankyou so much for all your help :)

Comment: A couple tips. First, we're not a discussion forum, so "thank you" comments are discouraged (use votes and accepts instead). Second, be sure to reply directly to the person you're addressing. Michael isn't down here. :) You can also use @ mentions (see the help link at right when you're commenting). Finally, add new information to your question, not in random places that other would-be volunteers will miss. [Take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information.

Comment: He mentioned redwood 4x4 in the video, but I agree any 4x4 lumber will be plenty good. Given its outdoor location, I'd go with PT pine or cedar / redwood.